# Spring 4.X set content-type of response to XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, response

I am currently building a webapp using Spring. My frontend application requests its data in XML format. This is working fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer and MS Edge. Both of them label the response as Text/HTML, which seems to be an issue for the javascript component used in the frontend.

How can I label the response as application/xml? Here is the Java code which produces the response:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboardData",  method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")
   @ResponseBody
   public ModelAndView getBereichsleiterData() {
       HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap();
       List<Map<String, Object>> data = dataProvider.getEintraege();


       model.put("total_count",dataProvider.getEintraegeCount());
       model.put("pos_start",0);
       model.put("table", data);

       return new ModelAndView("data/gridData", model);
   }
```

And the file under data/gridData is a .jsp which is used to render the XML:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 

pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows total_count='${total_count}' pos='${pos_start}'>
<c:set var="id" value="${pos_start}" scope="page" />
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${table}" varStatus="loop">
    <c:set var="id" value="${id + 1}" scope="page"/>
        <row id='${id}'>
            <cell>${entry.GEN_REKL_KEY}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.ART}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.WGR}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.EAN}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.HERSTELLER_NAME}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.BETRIEB}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.STATUS_ID}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.PROZESS_START}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.LETZTE_BEARBEITUNG}</cell>
            <cell>${entry.AKT_BENUTZER_NAME}</cell>
        </row>
    </c:forEach>
</rows>
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the first line of your JSP?

Comment: How could I overread it. Thank you very much for pointing it out to me. Please answer the question so that I can mark your hint as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the content-type yourself. Check the first line of your JSP.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

That clearly states `contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`... So I would argue that actually in this case IE and EDGE are right and the others are wrong...

Change the content type to what you want and be done with it.